# How to pass if statement when output the number in the variable?

Tags: php

I am working on my PHP to check to output the number in the variable that if the string is contains then do something.

When I try this:

```
$attached_file = 'attid: ' . $attid . ' filename: ';

if(strpos($files, $attached_file') !== false) {
    echo "here.......................now";
}
```

It wont let me get pass so when I try this:

```
$attached_file = 'attid: 0 filename: ';

if(strpos($files, $attached_file') !== false) {
    echo "here.......................now";
}
```

It works fine. I can get pass on the if statement with no problem.

Here is the array for the `$attached_arr`:

```
Array ( [0] => attid: 0.1 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png [1] => attid: 0 filename: how-ajax-work.png [2] => )
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

//Connect to the database
include('config.php');

$id = '3';
$mailbox = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE id = ?");
$mailbox->execute([$id]);
$attached_arr = array();

// set the resulting array to associative
$row = $mailbox->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($mailbox->rowCount() == 1)
{
    $mailbox_attached_files = $row['attached_files'];
    $attached_arr = explode("\n", $mailbox_attached_files);
    $attid = 0;

    foreach ($attached_arr as $files) {
        $attached_file = 'attid: ' . $attid . ' filename: ';
        $attached = '';

        if(strpos($files, $attached_file) !== false) {
            echo "here.......................now";
            //$attached = trim(strrchr($files, ':'), ': ');
        }
        $attid++;
    }
}

$mailbox = null;
?>
```

Can you please show me an example how I could pass on the if statement when I output the number in the variable `attached_file`??

Thank you.

Comment: You have a syntax error (single quote) at line 3 `$attached_file' <---------` shoud be `$attached_file`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Thank you for notice a syntax error but I have already checking before I posting as I have forgot to remove the ' before I post it. Unfortunately the problem are still the same when I try this `if(strpos($files, $attached_file) !== false) {`

Comment: The problem I have found are from this line `$attached_file = 'attid: ' . $attid . ' filename:';`. If I try this `$attached_file = 'attid: ' . $attid` it works fine but I need to include the ` filename:` after the $attid. Any idea?

Comment: What is `$attached_arr`? it is never used.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, The problem you get is that you increment `$attid` by hall number = 1 on each loop thru array. Like an example of your array, occurrence of `0` shoud be on second iteration, but `$attid` will be already equal to 1. Here is my vision:

```
$attached_arr = array ( 
    "attid: 0.1 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png", 
    "attid: 0 filename: how-ajax-work.png"
    );
$attid = 0; //initial id
//
for($i = $attid; $i < 0.5; $i += 0.1){
    //run thru the array
    foreach ($attached_arr as $files) {
        $attached_file = "attid: " . $i . " filename: ";
        echo $attached_file . "\n";
        $attached = '';

        if(strpos($files, $attached_file) !== false) {
            echo "here.......................now\n";
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
    attid: 0 filename: //0.1
    attid: 0 filename: //0
    here.......................now//we get output
//second increment now $attid = 0.1
    attid: 0.1 filename: //0.1
    here.......................now // we get output
    attid: 0.1 filename: //0
```

Hope it Helps.